# LogStash Crash when not reaching the ElasticSearch output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a "LogStash Instance" where my output are a basic elasticsearch (localhost)

(I am using a multi-pipeline method).
When ES is ok, everything is working. I try to kill the ES instance to test the capability of logstash to wait the reconnection of ES and to send the "event queue".

But when ES is down, logstash crash... Is there any way to keep the instance waiting to reach the "output" ?

Error in the logstash log:

```
       [2018-04-24T17:16:34,970][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass>, :backtrace=>...
       [2018-04-24T17:16:41,335][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) exit
```